# Functions being returned as keys

Tags: function, stack

Newbie question here...I'm building a simple stack using a functional pattern and returning the push and pop functions as keys(I ofcourse don't want this)...I really am not sure why.  The function is operational, just returning those two extra keys...

This is what the return looks like...

```
{ size: 2,
  storage: { '1': 'test0', '2': 'test1' },
  push: [Function], <== don't want
  pop: [Function] } <== don't want
[Finished in 0.1s]


 function Stack () {

    var obj = {};

    obj.size = 0;
    obj.storage = {};

    obj.push = function(data) {
        var newSize = ++obj.size;
        obj.storage[newSize] = data;
    };

    obj.pop = function() {

        var newSize = obj.size;
        var deletedData;

        if (newSize) {
            deletedData = obj.storage[newSize];

            delete obj.storage[newSize];
            obj.size--;

            return deletedData;
            }
         };
        return obj;
     };


var stack = new Stack();


stack.push('test0')
stack.push('test1')
stack.push('test2')
stack.pop()

console.log(stack)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say "obviously" you don't want the object to include keys for the functions, but I guess to me it's not so obvious...  So what is it you do want to end up with?  In JavaScript a function reference is just another piece of data, and a method is just a function reference stored as the value for some key on an object.

If you want the user to be able to say `obj.push(...)` then you *do* want a `push` key on `obj` (so that `obj.push` means something), and you want its value to be a function (so that the `()` operator can be applied to it).

Now I am curious because your output block says the keys are `xPush` and `xPop` but those aren't the values you show in the code block.  Is that because of editing in the question?  If not I don't see how that could be the way you've shown it.

Comment: I fixed the xPush and xPop...I was playing with the code and copied in the wrong return...Maybe your right, maybe it's not obvious.  I guess my question is, why am I returning the push and pop keys with their respective function properties?  Am I suppose to be seeing those when I log this and furthermore, how are they actually being created...I'm just a bit confused as to why I'm actually returning those.

Comment: How are they created?  Well, you say `obj.push = function(data) { ... }`, so that creates a function reference and assigns it to the key `push` in `obj`.  The object you return (`obj`) has these keys because you put them there with those assignments.  Did you perhaps mean to put those methods on `Stack`?